# Convert Files.walk to rxjava Flowable

Tags: rx-java2

How to convert
`Stream<Path> s = Files.walk(root)` to `Flowable` from rxjava?
Note that we cannot simply use `Flowable.fromIterable(()->s.iterator())` because `Files.walk` throws `IOException`. Easiest way is to collect results from `Files.walk` and then create Flowable from iterable collection, but it does not seem to be an idiomatic way.

Comment: See https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Jdk8Interop#stream-to-rxjava

Answer (score 0):

I think that I have found a nice way to do this. `Flowable.using()` allows to create Flowable with some "underlying" resource. If `Files.walk()` fails with `IOException`, subsriber's `onError` is called, and after completing "resource" is closed (in this case `java.util.stream.Stream` with paths).

```
import io.reactivex.Flowable;

import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

final Flowable<Path> pathFlowable = Flowable.using(
        () -> Files.walk(Path.of("/nofile")),
        stream -> Flowable.fromIterable(stream::iterator),
        Stream::close
);
pathFlowable.subscribe(System.out::println, t -> System.out.println("Error " + t.toString()));
```